# Displaying complex dictionaries in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have a template that I want to fill with information regarding developers working on a project.

Each developer will have the following information to display:

```
type
title
first_name
last_name
skills
```

The trouble I'm running into is that each developer has many skills associated with them.

I've created the model like this:

```
class DevSkills(models.Model):
    dev = models.ForeignKey(User)

    skill = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

I'm trying to create a view that will populate the dictionary so that I can loop through each developer, display their info, then loop through each skill (to display them one at a time).

Here is the view:

```
def developers(request):
    """
    ..  function:: developers()

        Provide the page that shows the developer credentials

        :param request: Django Request object
    """
    devs = User.objects.filter(is_staff = True)
    dev_info = {}
    for dev in devs:
        dev_info.update(createDevDisplayDict(dev))
    data = { 'user' : request.user }
    data.update({ 'devs' : dev_info })

    return render_to_response("developers.html", data)
```

I've designated the `is_staff` field from `User` to indicate the user is a developer.

I've created a simple utility that helps me populate the embedded dictionaries so I can loop through them:

```
def createDevDisplayDict(user):
    """
    ..  function:: createDevDisplayDict()

        Create a dictionary for showcasing the developer

        :param user: developer who we are working with
    """

    userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(user = user)
    devSkills = DevSkills.objects.filter(dev = user) 
    dev_dict = {}
    user_dict = { 'dev_type'        : userProfile.dev_type,
                  'title'           : userProfile.title,
                  'first_name'      : user.first_name,
                  'last_name'       : user.last_name,
                }
    dev_dict.update(user_dict)

    skill_dict = {}
    for skill in devSkills:
        skill_dict.upate({ 'skill' : skill.skill })

    dev_dict.update(skill_dict)
    return dev_dict
```

My intention is to loop through each developer, create a "super" dictionary to contain each of their `user_dict` dictionaries (which are based on their `User` info) and add to that a dictionary for each of their skills.  Then, back in the template I want to loop through the "super" dictionary in such a way that it will present them something like the following:

```
James Taylor
Project Lead
Software Developer
    • Django
    • Python
    • JavaScript
    • JQuery

Elizabeth Norton
Design Lead
Graphic Designer
    • Edge
    • Adobe Photoshop
    • Adobe Illustrator
    • CSS
```

Here is the template I'm trying to work with:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <p>Our Developers</p>
</div>
    {% for dev in devs %}
        {{ dev.user_dict.first_name }} {{ dev.user_dict.last_name }}
        {{ dev.user_dict.title }}
        {{ dev.user_dict.dev_type }}

        <ul> 
        {% for skill in dev.skill_dict %}
            <li>skill.skill</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

When I see the page now it looks like this:

```
Our Developers
```

Yeah...nothing is getting populated.  Any suggestions?

UPDATE 1:
I've modified my utility per iMom0's suggestion.  I'm now using a list to contain each skill.  Like so:

```
def createDevDisplayDict(user):
    """
    ..  function:: createDevDisplayDict()

        Create a dictionary for showcasing the developer

        :param user: developer who we are working with
    """

    userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(user = user)
    devSkills = DevSkills.objects.filter(dev = user) 
    dev_dict = {}
    user_dict = { 'dev_type'        : userProfile.dev_type,
                  'title'           : userProfile.title,
                  'first_name'      : user.first_name,
                  'last_name'       : user.last_name,
                }
    dev_dict.update(user_dict)

    skills = []
    for skill in devSkills:
        skills.append(skill.skill)

    skill_dict = {'skill' : skills}

    dev_dict.update(skill_dict)
    return dev_dict
```

I can see the value in doing this - in fact, it's much more intuitive and I think I was making it too hard the other way.  But my template still shows up bare.  :(

UPDATE 2:

I know I'm on the write path now.  I put some logging in the view:

```
devs = User.objects.filter(is_staff = True, is_superuser = False)
dev_info = {}
for dev in devs:
    dev_info.update(createDevDisplayDict(dev))

for key in dev_info:
    for sub_key in dev_info[key]:
        logfile.write('{0} = {1}\n'.format(sub_key, dev_info[key][sub_key]))
```

And the logfile displays:

```
skills = [u'Java', u'Perl', u'C++', u'Python', u'Django']
dev_type = Software Developer
first_name = Rico
last_name = Cordova
title = Owner
```

So, it has to be a way I'm calling it in the template, right?

UPDATE 3:

I had a realization that I was disconnecting the `user_dict` and their `skills`.  So I modified the utility slightly to bring them into a single dictionary.

```
## Create a logging object
userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(user = user)
devSkills = DevSkills.objects.filter(dev = user) 
dev_dict = {}
user_dict = { 'dev_type'        : userProfile.dev_type,
              'title'           : userProfile.title,
              'first_name'      : user.first_name,
              'last_name'       : user.last_name,
            }

skills = []
for skill in devSkills:
    skills.append(skill.skill)

user_dict.update({ 'skills' : skills })

dev_dict['user_dict'] = user_dict
return dev_dict
```

This is a much better solution, in my opinion.  I'm still having trouble accessing the `user_dict` info in the template though.  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be using Django's ORM features to make this a lot easier (and, we'll see, get better performance), it's a great feature!

### Model code

```
class DevSkill(models.Model):
    dev     = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name = 'skill_set')
    skill   = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

We changed two things:

- Using a `UserProfile` `ForeignKey` instead of user will simplify the rest of the code. Since you have a `UserProfile` <-> `User` mapping anyway, this is not going to be an issue.
- We added a `related_name` attribute so that any `UserProfile` object now has a `skill_set` attribute which store it's list of `DevSkills`.

(Please note that `related_name` is not required, and Django will create a generic `modelname_set` attribute if you don't set it).
Also, `DevSkill` should be singular, the object is a single skill!

I also expect that you have the following for `UserProfile`, and created code assuming you did. You'll need to adapt if you don't.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user     = models.OneToOneField(User)
    title    = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    dev_type = # W/E you want
```

### In the view:

```
devs = UserProfile.objects.all() # Or W/E queryset would fit.
# Pass context & all.
```

### In the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <p>Our Developers</p>
</div>
    {% for dev in devs %}
        {{ dev.user.first_name }} {{ dev.user.last_name }}
        {{ dev.title }}
        {{ dev.dev_type }}

        <ul> 
        {% for skill in dev.skill_set.all %}
            <li>skill.skill</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

### Performance

Please be aware that this code (the one you're using now too, though) is going to absolutely kill performance. Indeed, we're doing several queries for each user (Hitting the database for their User and their DevSkills).

That's not a problem though, we can  use the ORM's [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) features to solve that issue:

`devs = UserProfile.objects.select_related('user').prefetch_related('skill_set').all()`
That way, we only do two queries, one for the `UserProfile` -> `User`and one for the `DevSkill`'s, for which the joining is done in Python, but you shouldn't care about that, Django does it for you.

Please be aware that `prefetch_related` is a Django 1.4 feature.

---

Footnote: the `UserProfile` stuff is going away in Django 1.5, check it out!

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not working for me.  If I use the query `devs = UserProfile.objects.all(is_staff = True, is_superuser = False)` I get an error because the `User` object has the `is_staff` and `is_superuser` attributes, not the `UserProfile` model.  How can I filter `UserProfile` by the users who are `is_staff` and not `is_superuser`?

Comment: Ok, I was able to use the last query you put `devs = UserProfile.objects.select_related('user').prefetch_related('skill_set').all()` but it returns all users.  I want only `is_staff` and not `is_superuser`.  How can I do that?

Comment: I got it!  I just handled it in the template with a simple `{% if dev.user.is_staff and not dev.user.is_superuser %}`.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Rico That will work, but you're still querying everything and only deciding whether or not to display it. If you have a large number of users, that can become an issue. You should use `UserProfile.objects.filter(user__is_staff = True, user__is_superuser = False)...`. The `rel__field` syntax allows you to follow relationships in queries.

Answer (score 1):

`dict.update` always overwrite the value of dict

```
In [2]: d = {'key': 'value'}

In [3]: d.update({'key': 'value1'})

In [4]: d
Out[4]: {'key': 'value1'}
```

Instead, you should use `list` and `list.append`.

And your template do not know what `user_dict` is, correct it,

```
dev_dict['user_dict'] = user_dict
```

Comment: @Rico d['key'] = value is the same as d.update({'key': value}) not d.update(value)

Answer (score 0):

This is a new concept for me - `dict.items` in a template.  The following is exactly how I was able to display what I wanted.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <p>Our Developers</p>
</div>
    {% for key, value in devs.items %}
        {{ value.first_name }} {{ value.last_name }} <br>
        {{ value.title }} <br>
        {{ value.dev_type }} <br>
        <ul> 
        {% for skill in value.skills %}
            <li>{{ skill }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You could use `dict.values()` if you don't need the `key`. But if you don't need the key, you should probably be using a `list` instead.